# How to find mean of DWORD array

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

For my assignment I need to add elements of a DWORD array and then find the mean and place it in the ebx register.

```
TITLE Assignment 2



INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
array1  DWORD   10h,20h,30h,40h,11h,12h,16h,14h,18h,22h,96h,44h,89h,17h,94h,27h,16h,82h, 33h
N = ($ - array1)/4
.STACK 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD 
DumpRegs PROTO
.code
   main PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET array1
    mov ecx, N
    mov eax, array1
    loop_start:
    add eax,[esi]
    add esi,4
    dec ecx
    jnz loop_start
    call DumpRegs
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0   

main ENDP
END main
```

I have found the sum of the array but division is confusing to me.  From what I've read it involves setting edx to 0 then using the div command.  How is division handled and where would I place it in my code?

Comment: You should place it where you want to perform the division. Just try it an see what happens. Your computer isn't going to explode.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction `mov eax, array1` needs to change into `mov eax,0` (or `xor eax,eax`)

Insert your division right below `jnz loop_start`

```
xor edx,edx
mov ecx, N
div ecx
```

Now EAX holds the mean and EDX holds the remainder of the division.

Comment: but EBX needs to hold the mean

Comment: @Josamoda: Then put the value in EBX: `mov ebx,eax`